# CodeIgniter can't call function from model in controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am fairly new to Codeigniter and am trying to call in a function from my model but I cannot get it to work. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong here?

Controller (farm.php):

```
<?php defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Farm extends CI_Controller {

        function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
            $this->load->model('harvest_first');
        }

        function harvest()
        {

            echo $this->harvest_first->harvest();
        }   
    }
```

Model (harvest_first.php):

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

    class Harvest_first extends CI_Model
    {

        public function __construct()
        {
            parent::__construct();
        }

        public function harvest(){
            return "THE FUNCTION";
        }
    }
?>
```

I am trying to echo "THE FUNCTION", but no matter what I do I cannot get it to work as expected.

Thanks,
Simon

Comment: What error are you getting? From the look of it no errors are there.

Comment: how are you calling your function ? do you try the url something like http://your_host/farm/harvest ?

Comment: Its not an error, its just not working as expected. I am calling it from website.com/farm/harvest the page loads fine without errors but the function just is not working. if I add a manual echo above and below the function call in my controller the above shows but the second does not.

Comment: `Harvest_first` model should be `Harvest_first_model`. Any model should contain `_model` at the end of the classname.

Comment: @machineaddict Where did you get this? I'm pretty sure it's not like that, also there's no mention in the manual (not even in the examples provided): ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

Comment: @Damien Pirsy: That's why I used the word `should` in my response, and not `must`. To complete my previous answer, using `_model` at the end of the classname is a personal preference, as it is very obvious what is it.

Comment: To answer the `OP`, I cannot see any problem with your method. I just tested it, and it works as expected, it prints `THE FUNCTION`. The local url where I tested it is `http://localhost/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/farm/harvest`. And the `CodeIgniter` version is, obviously, `2.1.3`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
class Harvest_first extends CI_Model
```

change to :

```
class Harvest_first_model extends CI_Model
```

and in controller call like this:

```
 $this->load->model('harvest_first_model');
```

and

```
 $this->harvest_first_model->harvest();
```

Comment: This did it, thankyou very much never realised you had to include model in the name.

Comment: Where did you get this? I'm pretty sure it's not like that, also there's no mention in the manual (not even in the examples provided): http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html

Comment: No, there is no rule of `naming conventions` in `CI`.

Comment: Tend to agree guys. Don't believe model is required in any naming convention. Suspect Simon forgot to do the load->model statement or misspelt or missed out the model name in the function call. Not trying to be smart. Just wouldn't want someone to get the wrong idea about how it works.

Answer (score 0):

[Check here](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html)

- There is no need to add "_model" to model that depends on you
- just Load the Model and that its use autoload.php and add model there it is a good pratices