# Cannot Show Variable Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

Any one can help me I got stuck in this error I'm using Codeigniter :

Call to undefined method M_data::getTotalSales()

an here's my Code so far :

Model [image: Model]

Controler[image: Model] 
View [image: View] 
Thanks

Comment: Class names must have the first letter capitalized with the rest of the name lowercase. Make sure your class extends the base Model class.
https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html#anatomy-of-a-model

Comment: Check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19180853/codeigniter-cant-call-function-from-model-in-controller

Comment: Next time try not to post images of your code when asking a question. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html#loading-a-model

Comment: Double check if `M_data` model has method called `getTotalSales`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your mistake is passing data in view,

in codeigniter you have to pass data like this :

**In controller file:**

```
$data['hasilSemua'] = $this->m_data->getTotalSales();
$this->load->view('v_dashboard', $data);
```

**Access in view:**

```
foreach($hasilSemua as $val){
     print_r($val);
}
```

Try this pattern , May be it helps you.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer but can you help me for more specific based on my sample , I still got error here

Comment: glad to help you@Riandy

Answer (score 0):

In your **model** you should use:

```
`return $query->result_array();`
```

In you **controller** something like:

```
$data['your_data'] = $this->your_model_name->your_function_in_model($id_if_you_need_specific_value);
```

and finally iteration can be done in **view**, like:

```
foreach ($your_data as $something) {
        echo $something['sql_field_name'];
    } ?>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the answer but can you help me for more specific based on my sample , I still got error here

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using CI 3.X

The file name of the model is `M_data.php` and code should be like this:

```
<?php
class M_data extends CI_Model{

   Your Code here

}
```

When you are loading the the model then code should be like this

```
$this->load->model('M_data');
```

When you are calling the model methods. then the code should be like this

```
$this->M_data->getTotalSales();
```

Again you are loading view incorrectly.

```
$data['hasilSemua'] = $this->M_data->getTotalSales();
$this->load->view('v_dashboard', $data);
```

Checkout the solution.

Comment: Thanks for up this again  :) its helping me